# How to add "Team - Show in History" to Eclipse's toolbar

Tags: java, eclipse

I find myself frequently doing `Team - Show in History` frequently in Eclipse (right click on file in Project Explorer). How can I add this to the toolbar? I've tried `Customize Perspective` but `Show in History` is not available under `Team`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use shortcut keys, which is more convenient than clicking on toolbar. Open preferences -> General -> keys, and search "show in history". set binding you like.